# flutter firebase facebook login not working on android due to a build.gradle problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, facebook-authentication

### it is working fine on iOS but facing this issue on android

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:generateDebugRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_auth:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8.1).
> Required by:
> project :firebase_auth

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 20s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

The version given by the facebook documentation doesn't work for me either.
That's the version i am actually using:

> implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8,9)'

Anyway, if it doesn't solve your problem, try to give more information like, the plugin you are using for the facebook authentication, its version, and the firebase_auth and firebase_core version of the plugin you are using

Comment: it didn't solve my problem i'am using firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.1
  flutter_facebook_auth: "^1.0.0"

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth,  flutter_facebook_auth version is now ^3.1.1, try to update the plugin's version

Comment: it didn't work after updating the version

Answer (score 0):

It just worked with me when i switched to windows (don't know how ) and the error still show on Mac OS after trying all available solutions